# Using checkboxes to filter table by boolean columns in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be able to filter the contents of my "Contacts" table by interests, and I am currently attempting to accomplish this through a series of Boolean properties representing each individual interest. The plan was that I was going to have a series of checkboxes on the Index page for each Interest that would allow the user to display only Contacts that had one or more of the appropriate Interest variables set to "true" for each checkbox that was checked (or all Contacts if no checkboxes were selected). As far as I can tell this is theoretically possible, but my research so far has not turned up any results as to how to perform this sort of filtering in this specific manner. Could anyone here perhaps point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Here is what code I have so far related to the problem:

EDIT2: I have a nominally working set of checkboxes in place, but now the filtering isn't working quite the way I want it to. I want the controller to send the view only whichever Contacts have one or more of the same variables set to "true" as the appropriate checked boxes, or all Contacts if no boxes are checked. What I have now works fine for single selections, but with multiple selections only returns entries that match *all* checked boxes. I would like to know how to conditionally filter more effectively and efficiently than what I have now.

Here is my model- the "Interests" string was just to make it more presentable in the Index than just a line of grayed-out checkboxes:

```
public class Contact : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool LikesClassic { get; set; }

    public bool LikesCountry { get; set; }

    public bool LikesHipHop { get; set; }

    public bool LikesMetal { get; set; }

    public bool LikesPop { get; set; }

    public bool LikesRap { get; set; }

    public bool LikesRock { get; set; }

    public string Interests
    {
        get
        {
            var interests = "";

            if (this.LikesClassic)
                interests = interests + "[Classic] ";
            if (this.LikesCountry)
                interests = interests + "[Country] ";
            if (this.LikesHipHop)
                interests = interests + "[Hip-Hop] ";
            if (this.LikesMetal)
                interests = interests + "[Metal] ";
            if (this.LikesPop)
                interests = interests + "[Pop] ";
            if (this.LikesRap)
                interests = interests + "[Rap] ";
            if (this.LikesClassic)
                interests = interests + "[Rock] ";

            return interests;
        }
    }
```

Here is my View- the checkboxes are in place but not yet functional

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactInterests.Models.Contact>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Classic: @Html.CheckBox("Classic")
    Country: @Html.CheckBox("Country")
    Hip-Hop: @Html.CheckBox("HipHop")
    Metal: @Html.CheckBox("Metal")
    Pop: @Html.CheckBox("Pop")
    Rap: @Html.CheckBox("Rap")
    Rock: @Html.CheckBox("Rock")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            Interests
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Interests)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Here is my Index ActionResult for my Contacts controller; again, it is crude but nominally functional, just not in the way I would have preferred:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Classic, string Country, string HipHop, 
string Metal, string Pop, string Rap, string Rock)
    {
        var contactList = from c in db.Contacts select c;

        if (Classic == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesClassic == true);
        }
        if (Country == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesCountry == true);
        }
        if (HipHop == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesHipHop == true);
        }
        if (Metal == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesMetal == true);
        }
        if (Pop == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesPop == true);
        }
        if (Rap == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesRap == true);
        }
        if (Rock == "true")
        {
            contactList = contactList.Where(c => c.LikesRock == true);
        }
        if (Classic == "false" && Country == "false" && HipHop == "false" && Metal == "false" && Pop == "false" && Rap == "false" && Rock == "false")
        {
            contactList = from c in db.Contacts select c;
        }


        return View(contactList.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Please provide what code you have and what you have tried so we can help you better.

Comment: You have 2 options - server side or client side filtering.  Client-side is relatively data intensive as it loads all the data then hides/shows the ones you want via jquery - but it's also relatively easy.   Server-side involves sending a request to the server to provided a filtered list.  If you have a lot of rows, then server-side will be the way to go as you can also apply paging at the same time and it hugely reduces the load on the browser / wait for the user to render.

Comment: Would server-side filtering involve a query with conditional modifiers tied to the checked boxes in the view built into the model controller? Because I feel like that's close to what I was most prepared to do.